# Effect of updating a table during a transaction, but not part of that transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I have spotted some application code that does the following (pseudo-code):

```
start-transaction (trans)
{
  update(tableA, trans)

  update(tableB, trans)

  update(tableC) // not in transaction trans - creates own connection and transaction

  update(tableD, trans)
}
```

The code is C# and the DB is SQL Server. The outer transaction uses ADO and the table C update uses Entity Framework.

The table C should in fact be updated as part of the same transaction but I'm wondering how bad the effect is at the SQL Server level - ie. is this just a bit rubbish for performance or are there other, more serious side-effects potentially lurking?

Comment: What is the ratio of read vs write operations on those tables? What transaction isolation level are you using? The impact may be very small or very great. Maybe create some baseline performance metrics and measure the impact of the change before and after.

Comment: If the same data are touched by the update query on the second connection, that query will be blocked by the other connection.

Comment: If you need an update to be transactional, then it should be transactional. Whether or not it's "a bit rubbish for performance" is something a profiler can tell you afterwards, and then you fix it if necessary. Now, if "tableC" actually resides on an Oracle server on the other side of the world, necessitating a very expensive distributed transaction, it might be worth worrying over up front, but I don't get that from the question.